# Postfix + Python MIlter

Tags: postfix, milter

I want to write own miter, but I have problem.
I have installed postfix, libmilter and python module Milter.

I try to run sample.py milter which I found in pymilter-0.9.7.tar.gz (from http://bmsi.com/python/milter.html ) but I don't now how to add them to postfix.

I've tried 
set 
    smtpd_milters = unix:/tmp/pythonsock 
but postfix wrote to log
   connect to Milter service unix:/tmp/pythonsock : No such file or directory

python code http://pastebin.com/DXG0LFDU

Please help me, what i should do?

Answer (score 2):

Postfix probably runs in a chrooot environment.

Then you would have to put the socket in a place like this: `/var/spool/postfix/var/run/pythonsock`

Then also make sure that the permissions are correct. However, you would get a different message in the mail.log.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the [postfix Milter page](http://www.postfix.org/MILTER_README.html) before anything else, but if you're trying to use the `smtpd_milters` setting, either your milter doesn't talk in that manner, or you've configured the path to the file incorrectly.

I'd say by the pymilter [FAQ page](http://bmsi.com/python/faq.html), the first case is the correct example, as they offer up the `inet:host:port` configuration example (in sendmail syntax).

Answer (score 0):

This may sound obvious, but it did confuse me for a while. Your Milter has to run (and open the socket) before Postfix can connect to it. Essentially, you need each Milter to run as a dæmon outside of Postfix.

I had thought that Postfix would call the Milter on-demand for each message, like a Sendmail script.